# How to delay evaluation of Tuples[list,n] when n is a variable to be optimized through NMinimize?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, evaluation, hold

I am trying to do a linear optimization on a variable `i` where an intermediate variable `v` is needed:

```
Reproduce[]:=
Module[{v,c1,obj,var},
v = Tuples[Range[3,4],i];
c1 = 2 <= i <= 10;
obj = Total[Flatten[v]+i];
var = { i \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers };
NMinimize[{obj,c1 }, var]
]
Reproduce[]
```

In its current form the code does not run and throws a `Tuples::ilsmn: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of Tuples[{3,4},i].`

My assumption is that `Tuples[list,n]` requires an integer, but I am trying to feed it with an expression/unevaluated-variable (whatever this means in Mathematica language).

How do I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some wrong syntax, and you also have to define the objective function as one that will only accept numerical inputs:

```
Reproduce[] := Module[{v, c1, obj, var},
  v[i_?NumericQ] := Tuples[Range[3, 4], i];
  c1 = 2 <= i <= 10;
  obj[i_?NumericQ] := Total[Flatten[v[i]] + i];
  NMinimize[{obj[i], c1, i \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers}, i];
 ]
Reproduce[]
(* {44., {i -> 2}} *)
```

Comment: @WaterFox I can't guarantee that this will yield the correct answer, though, since I don't know what you're actually trying to do.  Some basic testing indicates that the minimum always happens for $i=2$, and it looks like it takes a long time to run of you use something like `Range[2, 7]`.

Comment: Oh I see so you transform everything to a function of the actual variable. That's smart! I think you solved my problem, it was really a syntax problem - the actual optimization is a detail, I gave here a dummy equivalent that is a bit nonsensical. It should not take too long as I can guarantee that `Range[a,a+1]` applies :)

Comment: Does `obj` has to be a function of all variables defined in `vars` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Since `v` us a function of `i`, `obj` is strictly a function of `i`.  What's important is that `obj` is a function of `i` explicitly since that's the variable you're minimizing with respect to, and that it will only be called if fed with a numeric value.

Comment: What I meant is in the case of two dependent variables `i` and `v`,both to be optimized upon, such that `i \[Element] Integers, v \[Element] Vectors[i,Reals]`, I don't know if `obj` should be a function of `i`, or both `i` and `v`.

Comment: @WaterFox That seems significantly more complicated due to the nesting.  You can't minimize with respect to a *vector* in *Mathematica*, I think; you have to minimize with respect to the *components* of the vector. The problem, then, is that there are a variable number of components depending on the value of $i$, and it's not clear to me how you would implement that in *Mathematica*.  I'm sure it's possible, but I can't think of an obvious way to make that work.

Comment: Ooof I see, so it's not possible to optimize over the components of the vectors if these components come in unknown number (i.e. the dimension of the vector is not know). The problem extends to Matrices, as I just painfully discovered :D